# How to insert two item which are String and Drawable in a single line of Hashmap?

Tags: java, android, string, hashmap, android-drawable

I have an issue here. I want to put a string and a drawable in a single hashmap. Since I'm really new to java, I'm not familiar with java syntax and declaration and I don't how to find the solution regarding my problem in the internet, that's why I come here. Basically my code looks like below:

```
private static String getAvModeText(String mode){
    String avMode = mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_stand);
    HashMap<String,String> mapAvM = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_STANDARD, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_stand));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_MOVIE, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_mov));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_MOVIE_THX,mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_movTHX));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVM_GAME, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_game));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_PC, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_PC));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_CUSTOM, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_user));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_DYNAMIC, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_dyn));
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_DYNAMIC_FIXED, mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_dynFix));

    if(mapAvMode.containsKey(mode)) {
        avMode = mapAvMode.get(mode);
    }
    return avMode;
```

}

I want to make my code looks like this:

```
mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_MOVIE_THX,mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_movTHX + " " + R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

But if I make it like this, there is an error and the error is at the getString() which is:

```
The method getString(int) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

So if anyone know how to solve this, I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: what is `mContext` here, show the declaration for this

Comment: the `mContext` declaration is `private static Context mContext = null;`. this code is actually long. so i just take a portion that i want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Create class like

```
public class Video {
  public final int title;
  public final int drawable;
  public Video(int title, int drawable) {
    this.title = title;
    this.drawable = drawable;
  }
}
```

then create map with `<String, Video>` generic type

```
Map<String,Video> mapAvM = new HashMap<String,Video>();
```

Comment: why video? can i put `Drawable` instead?

Comment: You said "How to insert two item which are String and Drawable", so i create class that contains two item.

Comment: If you don't want string,  `Map<String,Drawable> = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();` and put drawable by `mapAvM.put(yourKey, mContext.getDrawable(drawableId))`

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you'd like to do and unfortunately HashMap in Java doesn't work that way. Basically the first parameter is the key and the second is the value. So you should do something like this.

```
HashMap<String, Drawable> mapAvM = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_STANDARD, mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Then if you need to access the drawable later on, you can call:

```
  mapAvM.get(TvFunctionID.AVM.AVM_STANDARD);
```

which will return your drawable.